# How to access the value of variable `a` in first php script to second php script and linked by ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**Example: *my code in first php script:***

```
<?php
$a = array('green','yello','blue');
```

***Then in my second script:***

```
<?php
echo $a; //display the value based on my first script
```

> jQuery-AJAX links the two scripts

**PURPOSE:**

I have navigation bar in my web page that has 3 menu/option. Once i click one of the menu, i'll send it's index to the second script using this code `$(this).closest('li').index()` (which works correctly). then the second script will check the value of the index being sent....the index will serve as the key of the array...

**PROBLEM:**

Can't get the value (array) of `$a` in my second script

**NOTE:**

Can't I use only one script since i want to catgorize the scripts.....this is only small part of my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP variables are available always only within one request. New request means new scope and the variables set up in the previous script were forgotten. To keep a value across multiple requests, you may use for example session.

### Solution with sessions

**Script 1**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['a'] = array('green','yello','blue');
```

**Script 2**

```
session_start();
$a = array('green','yello','blue');
```

---

### Solution with require()

The other option would be to include the script 1 where the array is declared and initialized to the script 2 (and to all other script where you need the array).

**Script 1**

```
$a = array();
```

**Script 2**

```
require('script1.php');
$b = $a; // feel free to use the array $a here
```

---

### Solution with passing the array to the client and back

Yet another solution (even though most likely not a good one) would be to use `json_encode($a)` to encode the array as a json, send it to the client and then in the ajax request send the array back to the server to the script 2. Script 2 would parse the json using json_decode().

Comment: thanks for the info about the php variable request...didn't know that one...and forgot the $_session thing....thanks a lot, it woks. . .aside from $_session, is there another way?

Comment: aside from $_session, is there another way?

Comment: @NoelB. Yes, include the first file in your second page. `<?php include('script1.php'); ?>`

Comment: why `json_encode` is not the good one? .. anyways thank you Anton

Comment: @NoelB., you are welcome. Not that `json_encode` is bad (actually, it is very useful), but I meant sending the data to the client and back to the server might not be a good idea in your case. First I do not know if the data are confidential (anything you sent to the client can be read by a user unless it is encrypted). Second thing is pointless increase in traffic and site load time. Third thing is that user may modify the data on the client side (let's say the user is a curious developer or hacker) and send some garbage back to the server which is in worst case security risk.